# How to replace all occurrences using sed

Tags: sed

I couldn't make it work the way I want.

```
echo 'https://aaa/xx_one/bbb/xx_two/ccc' | sed 's|^\(https://.*\)xx_|\1OK_|g'
https://aaa/xx_one/bbb/OK_two/ccc
```

The output I wanted is: `https://aaa/OK_one/bbb/OK_two/ccc`

That is, I just want to replace every occurrences of `xx_` with `OK_` and with that specific constraint.

Need some help. I want it in `sed`. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `s/xx_/OK_/g`?

Comment: I want to constrain it via the `^\(https://.*\)`. That is, it must start with that value.

Comment: Try this `sed '/^https\:\/\// s/xx_/OK_/g'`

Answer (score 1):

If the line should start with `https://`, which you originally didn't say, you can use an "address" in sed:

```
sed '\=^https://= s/xx_/OK_/g'
```

Original answer: (will replace `xx_` by `OK_` after `https://`, but the line doesn't have to start with it).

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe '1 while s=https://.*\Kxx_=OK_=g'
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line, prints each line after processing;
- `\K` in a regular expression forgets what's been matched so far. In this case, it will only replace the `xx_` by `OK_`, but it still has to match `https://.*` before it;
- The substitution runs in a while loop until there's nothing to replace.

Comment: Thanks. I will upvote, if you can also make it for `ftp://` using one command in sed and not using `-e`

Comment: @eigenfield: Change the address to `\=^\(https\|ftp\)://=`.

Comment: Your use of the `=` symbol as posted above works but I'm curious why you choose `=` symbol? The obvious and most common would look like: `sed '/^\(https\|ftp\):\/\// s|xx_|OK_|g'`  wherein I use the `/` symbol for the addressing pattern. Here, you used `=` where first occurence is escaped and the second not.

Comment: You can replace `/` by any character if you backslash the opening one. I do it when the pattern contains `/` so I don't have to backslash it, to make the expression more readable.